# Use wildcard with different analyzer than the standard one in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I need to allow text free search for values containing dashes, so like `ABCD-12EF`.

I know that the `standard` analyzer does not work well with `-` because it splits the content in multiple tokens. I've created an index like the one below to try out `keyword` and `whitespace` analyzers but it seems like that the `*` chars does not work anymore. I get results only if I search for the complete value without `*` so `ABCD-12EF`. If I search for `ABCD-12EF` or `ABCD-12*` or `ABCD*` I dont'get any result.

Any idea why?

```
public class IndexTryOut
{
    [Key, IsFilterable]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable]
    [Analyzer("keyword")]
    public string Data1 { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable]
    [Analyzer("whitespace")]
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom analyzer that uses a “keyword” tokenizer with a “lowercase” token filter - see my answer to this question: [How to index a field with alphanumeric characters AND a dash for wildcard search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346822/how-to-index-a-field-with-alphanumeric-characters-and-a-dash-for-wildcard-search/55363420#55363420).